# Rename all variables in C++ project by naming style

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

How I can rename all variables and functions to suggested with name style in all C++ project?

I setup name style in ReSharper. I know that in C# project I could apply naming style for all project. But in C++ I don't see this setting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bulk rename [is not supported yet](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-20226/Bulk-inconsistent-naming-fix) in ReSharper C++.